# HTML Form Submit to table in same page

Tags: posts, forms, html, table

I have the form and works fine. On submit I have no idea where the data is going. I want it to go into a table on the same page. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="post" target="_parent">

<p>Date: 
  <input type="date" cf_name="Date" value="" maxlength="25" size="60">


Weight:
    <input type="text" cf_name="Weight" value="" maxlength="25" size="60">
</p>

<p>Comments:
    <input type="text" cf_name="comments" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
</p>

<p>Insert Picture (optional):
    <input type="text" cf_name="pic1" value="" maxlength="200" size="60">
</p>


<p> 
  <input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit" cf_name="submit">
  <input type="button" cf_name="cancel" value="Cancel" onClick="closebox()">
</p>
</form>

<table id="details"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things with this. Your action attribute is empty. That's the attribute that tells the browser where to send the posted form data. Should be a field or if you're using AJAX, I always put # in there and let the javascript do it's thing.

Not sure about the `cf_name` attribute in your input fields. I seem to remember that might be an implementation of Adobe ColdFusion but it's certainly not HTML compliant.